# Proof Verification Relational Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am trying to solve this logic puzzle.

May you tell me if my answer is correct?

Thank you for your help!

***No doctor who prescribes medicine with side effects for a patient who has no ailment will be respected by any of his peers unless he or she has a large practice or a large bank account.***

$\forall x \{[Dx \land \exists y (Py \land \exists t (At \land \neg Hyt) \land \exists r (Mr \land Sr \land Txyr))] \rightarrow$

$  [\forall u (Ou \rightarrow \neg Rux) \lor \exists w (Pw \land Hxw\land Lw) \lor \exists z (Bz \land Lz)]\}$

Comment: I improved formatting. Take a look at how you show these logical symbols so you can do this for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need a predicate $Hxz$ added at the very end (though inside the scope of the $\exists z$ of course), but otherwise it is good!

Comment: Thank you for your fast help! I will try to learn Latex when this semester is over.